# Correct way of retaining database information with fastapi and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi

we've recently changed tech stack for our python API so it now uses fastAPI and SQLAlchemy 2. Great combo, I'm sure, but I'm having issues creating something which I'd imagine would be pretty simple. I'm trying to build a simple post endpoint which takes a request body, processes it, adds it to the database, then return the inserted database entity. Something like this:

```
async def create_new_shipment_with_full_data(
    session: AsyncSession, data: FullShipmentCreationRequestBody
) -> Shipment:
    async with session:
        shipment_data = data.model_dump(exclude_none=True)
        cursor = await session.execute(insert(Shipment).values(**shipment_data).returning(Shipment))
        inserted_shipment = cursor.scalar()
        await session.commit()
    
        return inserted_shipment
```

This of course doesn't work (wouldn't be here if it did) since the shipment data seems to be lost once the session commits, yielding me this error:

MissingGreenlet("greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place?")

Now, I've tried solving it by expunging the instance from the session, but that doesn't seem to help in this situation. I've also fixed a similar endpoint by converting the shipment to a dictionary, yet I don't know if this is the best solution.

I'm really asking about the correct way of implementing this type of endpoints using fastapi and sqlalchemy. It feels like a very standard use case and I've been trying to get help from chatgpt which has currently shown me around 467 ways which don't work. Why does this feel like rocket science?

Thanks in advance

Comment: two "quick" suggestions you can try, make sure your session has `AsyncSession(expire_on_commit=False)` and / or if you have a relationship try to use an eager loading strategy such as `relationship(lazy='joined')`

Comment: To expand on what @python_user is saying, the MissingGreenlet error is usually caused when lazy loading happens and async has been used, as accessing a property isn't being awaited, and suddenly causes unexpected IO. By using a eager loading strategy (and using it by reloading the object, instead of returning an object which suddenly attempts to load elements outside of a await) this gets loaded in your first `await`, which means that SQLAlchemy doesn't have to attempt to retrieve it later.

Answer (score 0):

this error occurs when you try to pull up attributes synchronously, working in an asynchronous context, specifically in your case (I assume) that you have a Shipment object that has relation with `any-obj` object, and when you inserted something and indicated .returning, it will returns the Shipment object without any loaded relations, so after insert you have to `session.refresh(inserted_shipment, attribute_names=["any-obj"])` and its should fix your problem :)
also if you retrieve Shipment by id, for example, you have to load again `any-obj` attribute, it means:

```
async def retrieve(pk: int):
    stmt = select(Shipment).where(Shipment.id == pk).options(joinedload(Shipment.any-obj))
    result = await session.execute(stmt)
    return result.scalar()
```

or you may use `selectinload` (depends on your relations), read about it

you may read [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html) about it

Speaking about how the greenlet pops up, I’ll note that when you don’t load these attributes yourself, the pydantic tries to get them synchronously